# How to re-enable warning/errors of React app in console?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, npm, immer.js

I am using a typescript version of React and continue to coding. After 2 weeks I encounters with a bad functionality of React/webpack because these tools has been stopped showing me the warnings such as unused variable and so on. I didn't change anything. But recently there is a one problem and that is:

```
  found 1 high severity vulnerability
  run `npm audit fix` to fix them, or `npm audit` for details
```

And by running the `npm audit` I get the following message on CMD:

```
High            Prototype Pollution                                           

  Package         immer                                                         


  Dependency of   react-scripts                                                 

  Path            react-scripts > react-dev-utils > immer                       

  More info       https://npmjs.com/advisories/1603
```

And by going to the referred link, there was a solution to update the "immer" package. But my package was updated!!

the functionality I expect to see is like the below image:

[image: React warnings of unused variable definition on console]

Comment: Related: https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/10411

Comment: oh you said this is a unresolved bug?? Is there any way to solve that? I found this problem is open now! @Dominik

Comment: I'm not sure how the bug is related to your linting not working but it is related to the immer audit alert.

Comment: As the introduced github issue have been fixed and I have updated the package the warning is gone. But the problem of not showing the console warning is still not being solved :( @Dominik